# Angular 5 Load CDN script tag from Angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

I am using Angular 5 for the project.

My index.html looks like this :-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PDL Web</title>
    <link href="/assets/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <base id="baseHref" href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

My question how to add the script tag of CDN resource from the angular-cli.json file ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably leverage environment variables for this.

> Angular CLI projects already use a production environment variable to enable production mode when in the production environment
>
> It’s easy to add new environments in Angular CLI projects by adding new entries to the environments field in the .angular-cli.json file.  That can then be initiated with `ng build --env=dev:`

```
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Then create the file `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  cdn: '/url/cdn.com'
};
```

Then add the script tag in your app-root html (don't forget to import the einvironment into you component.ts):

```
<script src="{{environment.cdn}}"></script>
```

Comment: It is just printing <script src="{{environment.cdn}}"></script> as it is

Comment: Thanks for the help